# How can I get dotted boundaries on a RegionPlot?

Tags: plotting, regions

How do I plot something like $$\{(x,y): 1 \leq x^2 + y^2 < 9\}?$$

I want to be able to make the boundary $x^2 + y^2 = 9$ dotted line and the unit circle filled and coloured region in between? I tried using

```
RegionPlot[1 <= x^2 + y^2 < 9, {x, -3.5, 3.5}, {y, -3.5, 3.5}, 
  Frame -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Axes -> True]
```

But that gave me a bolded boundary on $x^2 + y^2 = 9$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All you're missing is the option for `BoundaryStyle`

```
RegionPlot[1 <= x^2 + y^2 < 9, {x, -3.5, 3.5}, {y, -3.5, 3.5}, 
 Frame -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Axes -> True, 
 BoundaryStyle -> {Dotted, Thickness[0.005]}]
```

[image]

If you want the unit circle filled, you can RegionPlot that separately:

```
Show[RegionPlot[1 <= x^2 + y^2 < 9, {x, -3.5, 3.5}, {y, -3.5, 3.5}, 
  Frame -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Axes -> True, 
  BoundaryStyle -> {Dotted, Thickness[0.005]}], 
 RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 < 1, {x, -3.5, 3.5}, {y, -3.5, 3.5}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red, BoundaryStyle -> {Dotted, Thickness[0.005]}]]
```

You can find all these (and more) in the help for `RegionPlot`.

Comment: Your second code gives me a red filled unit circle.

Comment: Nvm I got it fixed. thanks

Comment: You did say "and the unit circle filled" so I filled the unit circle with Red... or not...

Comment: No that would be the unit disk.